# Determine if context is a Specific Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-context

I'm passing the Activity context to a dialog but that dialog is global to other Activities, so its possible that other activities create that dialog too. My question is how can I determine that Activity context is a specific Activity?

I'm passing ActivityContext like this :

```
private Activity ActivityContext;

public MessageDialog(Activity context,int DialogStyle,int Dialog_Layout,String Msg) 
{
    super(context,DialogStyle,Dialog_Layout);
    this.ActivityContext = context;
    this.Msg = Msg;
}
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can use instanceof:

```
if ( this.ActivityContext instanceof MyActivity ) {
 /// ....
}
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for, thanks. Is there any difference to using e.g. `AcvitityObject.getClass == MyMainActivity.class`  ?

Comment: yes it's different. If you use '==' it will compare the pointer at the memory not the comparison between instance. '==' will return true only the comparable instances are exactly same ( have same memory address )

Comment: Have been banging my head on this for some time...thank you so much @marcinj

Answer (score 14):

I know the question is in java but if you are looking the answer in the kotlin :

```
if (this.activity is AppActivity) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Very nice! I also like the `(this.activity as? AppActivity)?.let { /* your code where "it" is the casted activity */ }`

Answer (score 0):

```
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    if (context is MyInterFace) {
        interfaceVariable = context as MyInterFace
    }
}
```